# Finding "integer" vector that minimizes scalar product

Tags: calculus, probability, optimization, vector-spaces, approximation

Assume I have a vector $a$ (with $a_i \in [-1, 1]\ \  \forall i$ )and a vector $x$ in $\mathbb R^n$. Let $q$ be a vector $\in \mathbb R^n$ such that every component $q_i$ is in the form $\frac ls$, with $s$ a fixed integer and $l$ an integer between $-s$ and $s$: $q_i \in \left\{\frac ls, l \in \mathbb Z, -s \le l \le s\right\}$.

I want to choose the vector $q$ such that it is as close to $a$ as possible, with "close" meaning that minimizes the difference between the scalar product with $x$, i.e. it minimizes the quantity

$$\Delta = |q \cdot x - a\cdot x|$$

How can I find such a vector $q$? I assume an exact solution is probably to complex, but I am also interested in approximations. For example, one of the things I am interested in is make sure that the percentage error is smaller than a certain value $\delta$, i.e.

$$\frac{\Delta}{a \cdot x} \le \delta$$

This of course may or may not be possible depending on $s$, but it would be nice to have a rough indication on how big $s$ needs to be to be able to satisfy that bound and to find any solution (not necessarily the best one) that results in a percentage error smaller than $\delta$.

A paper that goes into this direction is "Probabilistic construction of deterministic algorithms approximating packing integer programs" [Raghavan 1987](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022000088900037). I was wondering about other development aimed at solving the question; references to paper or partial results are also much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: This problem amounts to minimizing $\left|\sum_i k_ix_i - d\right|$ over all integers $k_i$, where $d = sa\cdot x$ is just a constant. If you can solve the problem when $d = 0$, then the solution of $d\ne 0$ is a trivial extension. I suspect that if the $x_i$ are idependent over the rationals, then the infimum will be $0$. I.e., you can make the sum as small as you like.

Comment: @PaulSinclair But the solution for $d = 0$ is trivially $k_i = 0$. How can you extend this when $d \neq 0$?

Comment: You are right - I was thinking that the constant could be subtracted from the $x_i$, but of course those are mulitplied by the $k_i$ while the constant is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given optimization problem can be written in the form

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & | \mathrm a^{\top} \mathrm z - b |\\ \text{subject to} & -s 1_n \leq \mathrm z \leq s 1_n\\ &  \mathrm z \in \mathbb Z^n\end{array}$$

which can be rewritten as a mixed-integer program (MIP) in $t \in \mathbb R$ and $\mathrm z \in \mathbb Z^n$

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & t\\ \text{subject to} & -t \leq \mathrm a^{\top} \mathrm z - b \leq t\\ & -s 1_n \leq \mathrm z \leq s 1_n\\ & t \in \mathbb R, \mathrm z \in \mathbb Z^n\end{array}$$

Comment: Thank you! So in this case we would have $b = sa \cdot x $, $z_i = l_i$ and $a = x$. I will try to implement this and see the results. In any case, do you have references to a more theoretical approach? Thanks!